# How to compare variable from js and twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatables, twig

I need to check statement of two variables one comes from my server and I access this from TWIG, second, comes from javascript (data table column value). I need to check like this

```
{% if key.orderid == 19 %}
```

Where 19 should be replaced with js variable.

Code for research:

```
// format function for row details
var fnFormatDetails = function( datatable, tr ) {
var data = datatable.fnGetData( tr );
            return [
                    '<table class="table mb-none">',
                    '<tr class="b-top-none">',
                    '<td><label class="mb-none">Produkt:</label></td>',
                    '<td>Ilość:</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '{% for index, key in orderProducts %}{% if key.orderid == 19 %}<tr class="b-top-none">',
                    '<td><label class="mb-none">{{ index }}</label></td>',
                    '<td>{{ key.productid }}   {{ key.amount }}</td>',
                    '</tr>{% endif %}{% endfor %}',
                    '</table>'
                ].join('');
};
```

Comment: You'll need to use ajax and send the javascript var to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your conditional statement in JS instead of twig.

```
var tmp = ['<table class="table mb-none">'];
{% for index, key in orderProducts %}
  if (19 == {{ key.orderid }}) {
    tmp.push('<tr class="b-top-none">','<td></td>','</tr>');
  }
{% endfor %}
tmp.push('</table>');
return tmp.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can does that

```
<script>var test = {{ valueToGet }};<script>
```